# JavaScript onresize event not firing

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to adjust the border width of my background image when the browser is resized. I'm calling that function `onload` and `onresize`. Unfortunately only the `onload` one is being called. So when I resize the browser I have to refresh the page to see the updated border width. No error messages in the console, everything else works perfectly- it's as though I hadn't even written an on resize listener.

```
w = window.innerWidth;
h = window.innerHeight;
hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(w * w + h * h);
borderWidth = window.hypotenuse/74;

function adjustBorder(width) {
    document.getElementById('tileBlock').style.borderWidth = width + 'px';
}

window.onload=function(){
adjustBorder(borderWidth);
}
 
window.onresize = function() {
    adjustBorder(borderWidth);
}

 <div class="wrapper" id="tileBlock"></div>

    #tileBlock {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #0b0b0b;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(photo.jpg);
    border: 20px solid #fff;
    background-size: cover;  
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are only defining your `borderwidth` the first time the javascript loads.  It needs to be changed when the window is changed.  Something along the lines of:

```
function adjustBorder(width) {
    document.getElementById('tileBlock').style.borderWidth = width + 'px';
}

window.onload=function(){
    var borderWidth = getBorderWidth();
    adjustBorder(borderWidth);
}

window.onresize = function() {
    var borderWidth = getBorderWidth();
    adjustBorder(borderWidth);
}

function getBorderWidth(){
    w = window.innerWidth;
    h = window.innerHeight;
    hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(w * w + h * h);
    borderWidth = window.hypotenuse/74;
}
```

Untested, try it and see if that helps.

Comment: Oh yes! Your code was almost perfect- thanks so much! I just had to substitute "getBorderWidth();" for your "var borderWidth = getBorderWidth();"